# Sitecore XP 1 Scaled installation on distributed servers

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I have four servers
1 Cd,
1 Cm,
1 analytics,
1 reporting and processing

I want to install Sitecore version 10.3 and after extracting the downloaded file, I can find some zip files and some json and a PowerShell file in the configuration folder. I have already installed it on my local computer (all on single machine) by adding all the zip and json files in a single folder and running the PowerShell file, but now I want to install it on the above mentioned servers so how am I supposed to update the PowerShell file script and the zip and json files folder structure. I want to run cm on the cm server and so on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can refer to this one. https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2022/06/26/sitecore-10-2-xp-scaled-installation-using-sif/

Comment: I have already followed the link you provided but it does not guide on how to structure files according to the different server, instead it adds all the files in a single folder

Answer (score 1):

To install `Sitecore 10.3 Scaled`, you can follow `Sitecore` documentation

[image]

Comment: I already followed the documentation and installed the sitecore 10.3 XP scaled version on a my local machine but now I have four servers and i want to get specific zip and json files on those servers in order to assign specific tasks to the servers. So I want any document that specifies about how we can make different scripts (PS files ) for the four mentioned servers

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** The below steps I tried with `Sitecore version 9.3`, I believe the same you can perform with `Sitecore version 10.3` and tweak accordingly. Hope it helps you.

1. First, you need to download Packages for XP Scaled from here
   Choose the right option as highlighted below:
   [image]
2. Create a folder named resourcefiles and extract and save the downloaded files into this folder. You can create it into C: drive like `C:\resourcefiles`. You will get the following files after extraction:
   [image]
3. Again, extract the XP1 Configuration files `9.3.0 rev. 003498.zip files` into the `C:\ resourcefiles` folder.
4. Install the Sitecore Installation Framework:
   => Open Powershell in administrator mode.
   => Run the below command to register the repository.
   `Register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2 -InstallationPolicy Trusted`
   here you can set InstallationPolicy parameter default Trusted so It would not ask you to press Y.
   => Install Powershell module, and run the below command:
   `Install-Module SitecoreInstallFramework`
   =>To update the SIF module to the latest version run the below command:
   `Update-Module SitecoreInstallFramework`
   => Set a specific version of the SIF using the below command, here you can go with the latest version 2.2.0 as it's compatible with SC9.3.0.
   `Import-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -Force -RequiredVersion 2.2.0`
   => You can find the list of the modules installed on your machine using the below command:
   `Get-Module SitecoreInstallFramework –ListAvailable`
5. Install prerequisites
   => Predefined Prerequisites.json file download and install all the prerequisites except below:
   Microsoft SQL Server
   SOLR
   => To Install the prerequisites configuration file run the below command in the PowerShell window:
   `Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path <ConfigurationPath>\Prerequisites.json`
6. Setup Solr:
   => To install SOLR run the below command with the required parameter:
   `Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path <ConfigurationPath>\Solr-SingleDeveloper.json -<ParameterName> <Value>`
7. Run XP Single Developer script for the XP Scaled Instance:
   => Save your Sitecore license file into the `C:\resourcefiles` folder.
   => Open `XP1-SingleDeveloper.ps1` file from `C:\resourcefiles` folder and update the appropriate setting as below:
   [image]
   => In the PowerShell command, go to the `C:\resourcefiles` folder and run the command:
   `.\ XP1-SingleDeveloper.ps1`

After completion of the script, you will get Sitecore XP Scaled Instance on your machine. Open IIS to verify and check scaled instances of SC 9.3.0. You will see below:
[image]

Run `https://xp1_scaled.cm/sitecore` and it will redirect to the Identity server login page, enter credentials and you will get your Sitecore CM environment as below.
[image]

See the blog post: [Install Sitecore 9.3.0 XP Scaled instance](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2020/05/install-sitecore-930-xp-scaled-instance.html)

Answer (score 0):

Adding more with the answer given by @Swati by referring to your comment on how to structure files according to the different servers, so once you download the **Packages for XP Scaled** using the Sitecore downloads, you will get `Sitecore 10.3.0 rev. 008463 (WDP XP1 packages).zip` file and when you extract the package you will see all the separate zip files for each server role. When you extract it, you will get all the files related to that server.
It looks like this.

[image]

So how you need to deploy using the XP1 configuration files, you need to refer to the Sitecore document called **Installation Guide for the XP Scaled topology**

Refer to [this](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/103/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_103.aspx) for packages and installation guide.

Hope this helps.